# Is there a better one liner to get parent dir?

Tags: php

```
realpath(__DIR__ . '/../') . '/'
```

I'm trying to assign the parent directory to a variable. This one liner works but I feel like there is cleaner way.

Comment: No, that's pretty much exactly how I'd do it. You  have everything right - using the `__DIR__` magic constant, expanding with `realpath()`, this is a great solution. Go with it!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dirname to get the parent of a directory...

```
$dir = dirname(__DIR__) . '/';
```

Comment: Maybe `dirname(realpath(__DIR__))` to be safe ? If `__DIR__` contains `/path/./` for some unknown reason, `realpath` is necessary for `$dir` to be correct. More realistically, it cleans up and resolves symbolic links in the path.